# Handling Incorrect Emails

Tags: email

Let's say my domain name is faketests.com (it's not) but people keep emailing various users at @faketest.com email addresses.  If I own both the faketests.com and faketest.com domains, how do I make it so that when someone emails anyone @faketest.com it automatically sends that email to the same user @faketests.com?

Comment: Could you name SMTP/MTA server software you use?

Comment: I'm using cPanel, so dovecot/exim are used